# How to configure spring-boot repackage with gradle-script-kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

With regular gradle I would configure a main class like so:

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'demo.Application'
}
```

With gradle-script-kotlin, this does not work.
I think I need to somehow use the `Project.configure` inline function, but I have tried a few different things and I haven’t been able to make it work.

Comment: Show your main class. Possible your class is `ApplicationKt`.

Comment: I have multiple main classes, which is part of the reason I need to configure it, if you have only one main class it gets discovered anyway.
No the problem isn't the class name, the above wont even compile let alone be evaluated.

Comment: so which error you get?

Comment: I have tried about 6 different ways of configuring the plugin all yielding various errors, I didnt include them in the question because I wanted to keep it concise and targeted to question at hand. Im not trying to solve an error, im trying to discover the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Okay, then please checkout this project: https://github.com/IRus/kotlin-meetup

Comment: @IRus That project uses regular gradle, gradle-script-kotlin is a new project that allows gradle build files to be written in kotlin rather than groovy.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i miss this point.

Answer (score 2):

**Update - September 8th, 2017**

In newer versions of the Kotlin support, you have a couple other more idiomatic ways to accomplish this:

```kotlin
tasks {
  "bootRepackage"(Repackage::class) {
    mainClass = "demo.Application"
  }
}
```

And also:

```kotlin
val bootRepackage by tasks.getting(Repackage::class) {
  mainClass = "demo.Application"
}
```

I'm sure the task will change in a new version of Spring Boot.

---

`bootRepackage` is a task of type [`org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/gradle/repackage/RepackageTask.java). With `0.4.1`, there are no extension methods available to make this configuration obvious. You will have to do something like the following:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.repackage.RepackageTask

(tasks.getByName("bootRepackage") as RepackageTask).apply {
  mainClass = "demo.Application"
}
```

Relevant open issues for `Task` configuration:

- [#34 - Support task selection and configuration](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/issues/34)